# How to return wildcard in Spock

Tags: wildcard, spock

I have something like this:

```
MyService myService = Stub( MyService) {
            filter( _, _, _ ) >> ...
}
```

and I'd like to return the first argument.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
filter( _, _, _ ) >> { return getArguments().get(0) }
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, by clicking the green checkbox next to it.

Answer (score 0):

`Closure` used in stubbing by default has an array of arguments used in given call. To just return the first one `it[0]` can be used.

```
MyService myService = Stub(MyService) {
    filter(_, _, _) >> { it[0] }
}
```

Btw, for more complex scenario it is possible to declare all the arguments with their types in a closure and use it to calculate a returned value.